# FInd .closest() fails

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have trouble understanding whys something like this wont work.
I have read [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) documentation and I don't see the mistake.

Code should look for a link and highlight the closest button.

The structure is simple:

```js
$('#meni').find('a').each(function() {
console.log(this);
      $(this).closest("button").css("color","red !important");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="meni">
     <button>button</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Also to note it this is part of bigger code, and the actual `this-link` will be in conditioned and return only one, so problem is not in that it sees multiple.

```
  var loc= window.location.href;
  //console.log(loc);

values=loc.split('/');
link=values[values.length-1];
//console.log(link);

    $('#meni').find('a').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).attr('href').indexOf(link) >= 0);
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(link) >= 0) {
      $(this).css({"color":"#87CEEB !important" , "font-weight":"bold" });
      $(this).closest("button").css({"color":"#87CEEB !important" , "font-weight":"bold", "border-bottom": "1px solid" });
    }
});
```

Comment: In what way does it 'not work'? Fail to highlight, fail to match? something else?

Comment: [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) checks the ancestors, not siblings.

Comment: @MikeBrockington It really couldn't be simpler to see what needs to be done from snippet. Seriously...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` (both jQUery's and the DOM's) look at *ancestor elements only*. It doesn't look at sibling elements, the parent's sibling elements, etc.

In your example, the ancestry of the `a` elements is `body > div > div > a`, the `button` isn't in that ancestry.

To find that button in that structure starting from one of those `a` elements, you'd use `closest` to find the outer enclosing `div` (probably giving it a class to make that easy), then `find` on that enclsoing `div`:

```js
$('.example').find('a').each(function() {
    const btn = $(this).closest(".example").find("button");
    console.log(btn.text());
});
```

```html
<div class="example">
     <button>button 1</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
     <button>button 2</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
</div>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you can't give it a class for some reason, `$(this).parents("div").eq(1)` will find it (`eq` is zero-based, so `.eq(0)` would be the nearest `div` parent, `.eq(1)` is the second-nearest):

```js
$('body > div').find('a').each(function() {
    const btn = $(this).parents("div").eq(1).find("button");
    console.log(btn.text());
});
```

```html
<div class="example">
     <button>button 1</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
     <button>button 2</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
</div>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but it's fragile — a small change to the markup will break it.

But if `#meni` really is the only element where this is done, just use `$("#meni button")` instead:

```js
$('#meni').find('a').each(function() {
    const btn = $("#meni button");
    console.log(btn.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="meni">
     <button>button</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

Side note: `$("#meni").find("a")` can be more concisely written `$("#meni a")`.

Comment: This is very well explained, thank you. And now i see obvious mistake. Yes I have a class on drop down from original HTML markup witch is much bigger, adding     $(this).closest(".w3-dropdown-hover").find("button").css   to my original code solved this. Good read up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```js
$('#meni').find('a').each(function() {
      $(this).parent('div').siblings("button").css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="meni">
     <button>button</button>
     <div>
         <a>link1</a>
         <a>link2</a>
         <a>link3</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```